# Selecting correct CSS element class/id in form for image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Very easy question, I'm sure, but finding it tricky to select an exact element that I need to run a bit of animation() on...

http://jmldirect.uat.venda.com/uk/cleaning/shark-steam-cleaning/icat/4fsharksteam

The red tags positioned on the images of the products move left into the overflow and get hidden. But the closest element I could use to use in the hover() method is:

```
#productList ul.gridStyle li
```

Not ideal as each li element is the whole listing, not just the image - which is the ideal. 
I have tried these also, but with no luck:

```
#productList ul.gridStyle li img
.prods .image img
jQuery('#productList ul.gridStyle li').children('img')
```

Because the images are generated using a form, I suspect this gives some context as to why it's not that straightforward?

**UPDATE:**

Decided that the correct selector to use is this:

```
#productList ul.gridStyle li .moredetail img
```

but running that up in the function does nothing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#productList ul.gridStyle li .moredetail img').hover(function () { //fired the first time
         jQuery('#red-tag-area img', this).animate({ "left": "-=80px" }, "slow" );
        }, 

        function () { // fired the second time 
                jQuery('#red-tag-area img',this).animate({ "left": "+=80px" }, "slow" );
            });
});
```

Comment: so what is your target element exactly?

Comment: The images within that page.

Comment: something like, `jQuery('#productList .gridStyle li .moredetail img')`?

Comment: '#productList ul.gridStyle li .moredetail img' should work.

Comment: Still nothing folks, which is weird because putting something like:
jQuery('#productList .gridStyle li .moredetail img').hide(); into the console DOES hide the pictures.

Comment: Maybe I can give a little more context (updating question)

Comment: I think using `this` for the second argument will tell jQuery to look for `#red-tag-area` inside of the `img`, so it is not necessary.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the images are loading dynamically, i suggest you to use $(document).on('hover','#productList ul.gridStyle li .moredetail img',function(){---your function code--}); . I am not sure this is the only issue but atleast you can give it a try.

Comment: Looks like you need to transverse backwards a few levels. The #red-tag-area should not be an id, it should be a class. Ideally the red-tag-area should be nested in the <form> tag. Then it would just be a matter of $(this) + img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#productList ul.gridStyle li .moredetail img').hover(function () { 
        jQuery(this).closest("form").siblings("#red-tag-area").find("img").animate({"left": "-=80px" }, "slow" );
    }, 

    function () { 
        jQuery(this).closest("form").siblings("#red-tag-area").find("img").animate({ "left": "+=80px" }, "slow" );
    });
});
```